# E/Web Console(8272): Uncaught ReferenceError: functionName is not defined:1 while loading webviews in a View Pager

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-viewpager

I am trying to load webviews in a view pager.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;      
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
    myWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();      
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/index.html");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testFunction()");
        }
    }
}
```

After loading the page, a javascript function is called in `onPageFinished()` 
While scrolling at normal speed the webpages are loading and the javascript is executed.

But while scrolling at high speed the following exception is occured.

```
> 09-06 14:29:06.750: E/Web Console(8272): Uncaught ReferenceError:
> testFunction is not defined:1
```

testFunction() is

```
function testFunction(){
    console.log("TestFuntion");     
}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a fix on this

just set webChromeClient and catch the error and reload the page...

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            isLoading = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testFunction()");
        }
    });

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            MessageLevel level = consoleMessage.messageLevel();
            if(level.ordinal() == 3) { // Error ordinal
                if(loading) {
                    myWebView.stopLoading();
                    myWebView.loadUrl(AppConstants.ARTICLE_PAGE_URL);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this and make changes as per your requirement

webview code

```
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    JavaScriptInterface JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "JSInterface"); 
    setContentView(web);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
```

javascript interface

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void showToast()
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

webpage code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
     var i=0;
     function myFunction()
     {

       JSInterface.showToast();
     }
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p>By clicking the button above, a function will be called. The function will alert a message.</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

```
function myFunction()
 {

   do here somthing
 }
```

Comment: Hi Ketan, I dont need to call the function in Android activity, I want to call a function in html file. My code works on normal scroll in view pager. Its throwing exception only when I do fast scrolling..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `Uncaught Reference Error: JavascriptInterfaceName is not defined` on every second startup of my hybrid application on 4.3 and below, and so I did this thanks to @Abi in my `WebChromeClient` class:

```
@Override
@SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "InflateParams"})
public boolean onConsoleMessage(@NonNull ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
    if("Uncaught ReferenceError: JavascriptInterfaceName is not defined".equals(consoleMessage.message())) {
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "JavascriptInterfaceName ");
        webView.reload();
    }
    return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
}
```

And it works! Thank you very much!