# How to get the HTML page elements (button, input, Images ) in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am loading online html page in my Webview, And want to load activity against the specific button clicked from html online page (not from local HTML page)

I find some thing but that is not responding against my requirement.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha");
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
                Log.i("TESTING In OnTouch ", "getExtra = "+ hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType()+
                        "\t\t Ancher Tag = " +HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE+
                        "\t\t Ancher Tag = " +HitTestResult.UNKNOWN_TYPE+
                        "\t\t Ancher Tag = " +HitTestResult.ANCHOR_TYPE
                        );
             return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you can code for HTML page then its possible using javascript. see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654009/e-web-console8272-uncaught-referenceerror-functionname-is-not-defined1-whil/18654172#18654172

Comment: Ketan you r using local HTML not On line page

Answer (score 1):

```
    int     ANCHOR_TYPE     HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag
    int     EDIT_TEXT_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an edit text area
    int     EMAIL_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an email address
    int     GEO_TYPE    HitTestResult for hitting a map address
    int     IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE   HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag which contains HTML::img
    int     IMAGE_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an HTML::img tag
    int     PHONE_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting a phone number
    int     SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE     HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag with src=http
    int     SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE   HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag with src=http + HTML::img
    int     UNKNOWN_TYPE    Default HitTestResult, where the target is unknown
```

HitTestResult class has only two method.

getExtra() : It return String. String has HTML element which is clicked by user

getType() : It return integer. It is used to identify which HTML element is clicked by user.

```
    public class MyWebView extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        WebView wv;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new VideoWebViewClient());
            wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio");
            wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

                    Log.i(TAG, "getExtra = "+ hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType());
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        private class VideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);

                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: as i try to long the getExtra it return only following.

getExtra = null Type=0. I required the element ID of clicked button.

Comment: Is there any other change in code to archive results. Above code is not working at my end.

Comment: Any other face same issue, your guidance will made me easy. Looking for your response.